# Can't mirror gitlab repo to github

Tags: github, gitlab, mirror

### I've tried inputting:

- `https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<repo>` + access token
- `https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<repo>` + password
- `https://@github.com/<username>/<repo>` + access token
- `https://@github.com/<username>/<repo>` + password
- `ssh://<user>:github.com/<username>/<repo>`

But none of them result in a successful update.
I have no clue what the issue could be, can someone explain step by step how to do this?
I have watched and read several tutorials but none have been able to get this to work.

### Notes

- The repo is public

Answer (score 2):

[Mirroring a GitLab repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) would work with an [authentication method](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/#authentication-methods-for-mirrors) which would be:

- **Public key authentication for SSH URL**, using a [GitHub deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys) registered to the target repository.
  Make sure the URL is:

  ```
  ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>
        ^^^^
  ```

  It is `ssh://git@github.com/...`, *not* `ssh://<user>:github.com/`
- Or: **password for HTTPS URL**, except that password is, for GitHub repository, a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).
  The URL would be:

  ```
  https://github.com/<username>/<repo>
  ```

  No need to add `<username>`, since your PAT will authenticate you anyway.

---

[user2156115](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156115/user2156115) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75194315/cant-mirror-gitlab-repo-to-github/75197703?noredirect=1#comment133619008_75197703):

[You need to add]  a Check Mark when copy/pasting a public key from Gitlab to Github to grand "write permissions".
It 's a little tiny checkbox you need to mark.

Comment: I have the same problem
this is my URL `ssh://git@github.com/xjantoth/unit-school.git` and the error is
13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n".

Comment: @user2156115 I suppose because the key used by GitLab to access the GitHub repository is not the right one. You can also try an HTTPS URL, using your GitHub user account and token as credentials.

Comment: It has been resolved by adding Check Mark when copy/pasting a public key from Gitlab to Github to grand "write permissions". It 's a little tiny checkbox you need to mark. Thx

Comment: @user2156115 Good catch, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.